Emoji literal vs emoji unicode-escaped
Why there is a difference in how an emoji is displayed in JavaFX depending on if you're using a unicode escaping or not?
var button = new Button("Toggle Pane >\u2699< >⚙️<"); - in first pair of brackets a gear emoji will be placed, but in second pair - there will be a gear emoji and an empty rectangle.
If same Java string will be printed to console instead of being displayed in GUI, there will be no rectangle.

Source .java file is UTF-8, you can paste emoji into text by pressing Win+; in Windows.
In Powershell there is also a difference:
"⚙️" | Format-Hex -Encoding utf32 | % HexBytes
# result: 99 26 00 00 0F FE 00 00
"`u{2699}" | Format-Hex -Encoding utf32 | % HexBytes
# result: 99 26 00 00

What's going on here?

Are you sure there is no invisible symbol after emoji?

If the editing is okay, UTF-8, still remains the java compiler thinking it has a different charset. by the way \uFE0F looks like a circle with 12 dots; probably not represented in the font.

@talex Looks like there is, second char FE0F is a variation selector which can be cut off if needed

Related question on emojis in JavaFX using various platforms and fonts.

Invisible symbol after emoji is a variation selector.
Win+; pastes it into text after emoji. It is invisible character (selected on screenshot) which can be removed from source code after pasting emoji or stripped of by "⚙️".charAt(0).
In VSCode you can't select/delete this second char because caret treats this pair of chars as a whole, but in Notepad++ you can select this invisible char and delete it.

What does u'\ufe0f' in an emoji mean? Is it the same if I delete it?

But note that the variation selector can change how the character is displayed quite significantly. On macOS it selects a larger color Emoji for the gear wheel, without it a smaller non-color character is displayed.

@greg-449 You mean it works properly in JavaFX on macOS? In Windows as you can see instead of affecting how emoji is displayed, it is just shown as an additional rectangle. In VSCode without this selector emoji is dislpayed as a text symbol, with it - as an image.

I don't use JavaFX, it works fine with SWT and on the macOS Terminal.

@Podbrushkin, there are two issues: 1) the presence of a variation selector which should force emoji representation rather than text representation; and 2) text being displayed by a non-emoji font even with the variation sleector present. The additional rectangle is the font's .notdef glyph.

@Podbrushkin the JavaFX emoji implementation on OS X is a bit different than JavaFX on other systems. On a Mac, JavaFX will use the Mac default color emoji font. Often this has good results not easily obtainable on other systems using JavaFX.  A cross-platform alternative is the Ikonli JavaFX software (which is a bit different anyway).
